# how can i convert image to binary image using php?

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing

Is there any way to convert Normal image to [Binary Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image) (two possible values for each pixel. i.e., a 0 or 1)  ?

i have found some solution in **Matlab** but i am searching for a solution in **PHP/JavaScript**.

Comment: I'd go with ImageMagick to do this.

Comment: please share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lovely picture I've just taken of my keyboard I whipped up this example for you that converts a source image to a dithered 2-colour palette based image:

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng('test.png');

imagetruecolortopalette($src, true, 2);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($src);
imagedestroy($src);
```

**Source:**

[image: source image before palette conversion]

**Result:**

[image]

If you don't want the dithering change the second parameter in `imagetruecolortopalette($src, true, 2);` to `false`:

[image]

---

***Edited to add:***

The picture above is very simple and practically 2-colour already. Depending on the complexity of your source image(s) the result might be significantly worse.